# Understanding Transient properties with NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, transient

I'm starting to create an application with Core Data, to retrieve a data for sectioned table i want to use NSFetchedResultController, in the [example](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/DateSectionTitles/Introduction/Intro.html) from apple there are two additional properties.

- primitiveTimeStamp
- primitiveSectionIdentifier

For the case of **primitiveSectionIdentifier** apple says that

> In contrast, with transient properties you specify two attributes and
>   you have to write code to perform the conversion.

because the sectionidentifier is transient property.
But what about the timeStamp ?this attribute is not a transient,  why there is a primitiveTimeStamp property ? and why there is explicit setter for timeStamp ?

```
- (void)setTimeStamp:(NSDate *)newDate {

    // If the time stamp changes, the section identifier become invalid.
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"timeStamp"];
    [self setPrimitiveTimeStamp:newDate];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"timeStamp"];

    [self setPrimitiveSectionIdentifier:nil];
}
```

or maybe it's not a actual setter? where is _timeStamp=newDate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CoreData generates the accessors for you. It generates "public and primitive get and set accessor methods for modeled properties".

So in this case it has generated:

```
-(NSDate*)timeStamp;
-(void)setTimeStamp:;
-(NSDate*)primitiveTimeStamp;
-(void)setPrimitiveTimeStamp:;
```

**"why there is a primitiveTimeStamp property ?"**

The declaration is merely to suppress compiler warnings. ie. If you removed the declaration of the property you'd find a warning on compilation but the code would still run.
Or alternatively you could use `[self setPrimitiveValue:newDate forKey:@"timeStamp"];`

**"why there is explicit setter for timeStamp ?"**

This is required since setting the timeStamp requires the 'sectionIdentifier' to be recalculated. This is achieved by setting it no `nil` and letting the get accessor recalculate it lazily.

**"where is _timeStamp=newDate?"**

The equivalent of this is essentially done in the auto generated implementation of `setPrimitiveTimeStamp`.

A quote from the docs:

By default, Core Data dynamically creates efficient **public and primitive** get and set accessor methods for modeled properties (attributes and relationships) of managed object classes. This includes the key-value coding mutable proxy methods such as addObject: and removes:, as detailed in the documentation for mutableSetValueForKey:—managed objects are effectively mutable proxies for all their to-many relationships.

Note: If you choose to implement your own accessors, the dynamically-generated methods never replace your own code.
For example, given an entity with an attribute firstName, Core Data automatically generates firstName, setFirstName:, primitiveFirstName, and setPrimitiveFirstName:. Core Data does this even for entities represented by NSManagedObject. To suppress compiler warnings when you invoke these methods, you should use the Objective-C 2.0 declared properties feature, as described in “Declaration.”

Comment: thanks for answer, but i didn't quite understand the meaning of all those properties with primitive prefix. Because as i understand Core Data generates primitive getter and setter for all attributes in Entity right ?  could you please also explain why there are two properties for single attribute